# Mobile broadband connection sharing with Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, network-shares, windows-10

I have  to share my Dell E5450 internal mobile broadband internet connection with some Hyper-V virtual machines.

The OS is Windows 10 PRO updated to the anniversary edition.

I tried several ways and tutorials, but unfortunately, despite to the working solution for the WiFi card, the mobile broadband modem does not allow to add itself to the bridge.

Does anybody known how to share the mobile connection with the Hyper-V virtual machines?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Android or Windows Phone? How do you connect your phone with PC? USB or WiFi or Bluetooth? Can you do tethering from phone to PC?.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on a german IT site: http://www.it-pro-berlin.de/2014/05/unterwegs-mit-hyper-v-mobil-ins-internet/

In short:

- add a pure internal virtual Switch
- activate ICS on the mobile broadband Adapter and connect it to the above Switch
- add virtual switch to VM network adapters